# Perl recursive file search for unicode filenames

Tags: perl, file, search, unicode, recursion

I've tried `File::Find::Rule`, but it doesn't reveal filenames that contain characters like:
 `בר רפאלי`

Any ideas?

```
use File::Find::Rule;
use Win32::Shortcut;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('status.xls');

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();


my $base_dir ='E:/files/';

my $find_rule = File::Find::Rule->new;

#$find_rule->maxdepth(1);

$find_rule->name('*.lnk');

my @files = $find_rule->in($base_dir);

print scalar(@files)."\n";

#print join("\n", @files);
```

Comment: They would be encoded as per your locale's encoding. On Windows, it's possible to encounter file names that can't be encoded as per the locale. I bet that's handled by returning the file's short name???

Comment: it skips the file, it doesn't show it at all.

Comment: use File::Find::Rule;
use Win32::Shortcut;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('status.xls');

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();


my $base_dir ='E:/files/';

my $find_rule = File::Find::Rule->new;

#$find_rule->maxdepth(1);

$find_rule->name('*.lnk');

my @files = $find_rule->in($base_dir);

print scalar(@files)."\n";

#print join("\n", @files);   I don't know how to format this text, so I've uploaded it here: http://pastebin.com/j8mV1vzr

Answer (score 0):

I have no way to test this (Linux, not too much Unicode knowledge etc) and its probably inefficient, but perhaps it will work in a "just get it done kind of way. You could use my [`File::chdir::WalkDir`](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3achdir%3a%3aWalkDir) and use a per-file callback that adds to the file name to a list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::chdir::WalkDir;
use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile';

my $base_dir = '.';

my @files;
my $callback = sub {
  my ($file, $dir) = @_;
  return unless ($file =~ /\.lnk$/);

  push @files, catfile($dir, $file);
};

walkdir($base_dir, $callback);
```

Since this leans on `opendir` and friends it may be slow, but as long as it can see your files, this should work. Give it a try and let me know if there are problems.

Answer (score 0):

see [Win32::Unicode::Native](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aUnicode%3a%3aNative) and http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=843602